# Can Github Actions have unit tests that create files and directories?

Tags: .net, github, nunit, github-actions

I have a unit test that requires some folders/files to be created. It works locally as I have permission to create the folders/files but this doesn't seem to work in Github Actions.

I have the following set up for Github Actions:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [windows-latest]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup MSBuild
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1

      - name: Setup NuGet
        uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

      - name: Restore NuGet packages
        run: nuget restore NewFolderSolution.sln

      # Run msbuild as we have "ResolveComReference" used
      # dotnet build doesn't support "ResolveComReference"
      - name: Build the solution
        run: msbuild NewFolderSolution.sln

      - name: Run dotnet test on new folder solution project
        run: dotnet test NewFolderSolution.sln
```

I am getting the following error:

```
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
  Failed TestNewFolderCreation[285 ms]
  Error Message:
   System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'D:\a\solution\project\folder1\NewlyCreatedFolder' is denied.
  Stack Trace:
     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String path, Boolean recursive)
   at NewFolderSolutionTest.Setup() in D:\a\solution\project\folder1\NewFolderSolutionTest.cs:line 23
```

Is there some permission that I need to set for this to work?

Edit: The issue seems to be related to deleting the directory

Comment: I don't know much about the Windows runners, but is that an absolute path on your machine?

Comment: It shouldn't be an absolute path. It should create a subdirectory `NewlyCreatedFolder` and new files in it under the test project's current directory.

Comment: FWIW, in the Ubuntu runner, that's not a problem at all. I don't think you need special permissions to create files and directories in the Windows runner, either. It depends on how exactly the test creates files and directories.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks @BenjaminW. I wasn't sure whether there were special permissions required to create directories/files. I'll have a second look at our test code and see if it needs to be tweaked

Comment: Find anything out?